# What are the non current assets in a balance sheet?

Tags: financial-literacy, assets, financial-statements

In order to know if companies are conservatively financed I query an API that gives me the financial information. Yet when if the information it gives for the current assets, I can't understand what are the non current assets. For instance this is the balance sheet of Microsoft:

```
>>> from yahooquery import Ticker
>>> ticker = Ticker("MSFT")
>>> ticker.balance_sheet()

        maxAge  endDate     cash    shortTermInvestments    netReceivables  inventory   otherCurrentAssets  totalCurrentAssets  longTermInvestments     propertyPlantEquipment  goodWill    intangibleAssets    otherAssets     deferredLongTermAssetCharges    totalAssets     accountsPayable     shortLongTermDebt   otherCurrentLiab    longTermDebt    otherLiab   totalCurrentLiabilities     totalLiab   commonStock     retainedEarnings    treasuryStock   otherStockholderEquity  totalStockholderEquity  netTangibleAssets
symbol  row                                                                                                                 
MSFT    0   1   2019-06-30  11356000000     122476000000    29524000000     2063000000  10133000000     175552000000    2649000000  43856000000     42026000000     7750000000  14723000000     7536000000  286556000000    9382000000  5.516000e+09    45860000000     66662000000     35699000000     69420000000     184226000000    78520000000     24150000000     -340000000  -340000000  102330000000    52554000000
1   1   2018-06-30  11946000000     121718000000    26481000000     2662000000  6855000000  169662000000    1862000000  36146000000     35683000000     8053000000  7442000000  1369000000  258848000000    8617000000  3.998000e+09    38195000000     72242000000     35707000000     58488000000     176130000000    71223000000     13682000000     -2187000000     -2187000000     82718000000     38982000000
```

I try to sum the `totalCurrentAssets` with the rest, which I guess are the non current assets?

```
sum(df.iloc[0, cols.get_loc('totalCurrentAssets')+1: cols.get_loc('totalAssets')].to_dict().values()) + df['totalCurrentAssets'][0]
```

And it gives me 294092000000, which is higher than `totalAssets` which is 286556000000

Answer (score 1):

Note that `294,092,000,000 - 286,556,000,000 = 7,536,000,000`, which is the exact value of "deferredLongTermAssetCharges".

If you exclude that column, then totalAssets equals totalCurrentAssets plus the 5 columns after that.

So in that dataset, non-current assets would be the sum of:

```
longTermInvestments
propertyPlantEquipment
goodWill
intangibleAssets
otherAssets
```

or just `totalAssets - totalCurrentAssets`